# JIRA integration with client application

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

We are integrating JIRA with our application using HTTP based Connector. We want to check whether the user has the right access to change the status of the tasks in JIRA. Does JIRA provide any APIs that can be called from the client application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can
[Jira Rest Api - Issue - get-transitions](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.4.3/#api/2/issue-getTransitions)

> GET /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions Get a
>   list of the transitions possible for this issue by the current user,
>   along with fields that are required and their types.
>
> Fields will only be returned if expand=transitions.fields.
>
> The fields in the metadata correspond to the fields in the transition
>   screen for that transition. Fields not in the screen will not be in
>   the metadata.